# Finding width and height of a .bmp image in C

Tags: c, image, height, width, bmp

I wanted to know if it is possible to find the width and height of a .bmp image in C. I've looked all over the place but all I could find is examples in c#, .NET and C++. However, I couldn't find any code related to C. Please help if possible.

Comment: Do you have an HBITMAP or are you wanting to do this with a .bmp file.

Comment: If it's a .bmp file then you can get the information you need from this Wikipedia article http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_File_Header

I'm assuming you'll have to write your own code to read the header and parse out the information you need.

I did something similar to this long ago, but I don't have a ready example.